# unable to display data using datatables with source as JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

My Jquery code:

```
$('#tableid').dataTable( {
           "processing": true,
           "serverSide": true,
          "ajax": {
                         "url": url,   ---> My call to servlet
                        "type": "POST",
                    "columns": [
                        { "sTitle": "FName" },
                         { "sTitle": "Mname" },
                        { "sTitle": "LName" },
                    ]
                    }
                } );
```

My JSON string coming from backend is:

```
[{"Fname":"abc","Mname":"ezc","Lname":"JSH"}]
```

My HTML page:

```
<table id="tableid" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FName</th>
                <th>Mname</th>
                <th>Lname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I am not sure what am I missing here. There are no validation errors. Result is not getting displayed on the page.

Comment: I think your json value needs to be called `data`: [https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#Types](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#Types)

Answer (score 0):

```
Got this running.

Jquery code to be used:
 var posting = $.post( url );
              posting.done(function( data ) {
                  $('#tableid').dataTable( {
                      "aaData": data,
                      "columns": [
                            { "data": "Fname" },
                            { "data": "Mname" },
                            { "data": "Lname" }
                            ]
                  });

         });

Added 
<td> tags in html for respective fields.

Will be useful to those who want to fetch the data from backend in json string and display in datatable.
```